# Not able to run if condition inside Makefile

Tags: shell, makefile

I have the following content in my makefile:

```
ARCH := $(if $(GOARCH),$(GOARCH),$(shell go env GOARCH))

all: build

build:
    echo "Doing the build"
    if [ "$$ARCH" = "amd64" ]; then \
        touch test; \
        echo "inside the condition loop"; \
    fi
```

Now, while running `make` command, I get the following output:

```
# make
echo "Doing the build"
Doing the build
if [ "$ARCH" = "amd64" ]; then \
    touch test; \
    echo "inside the condition loop"; \
fi
```

This executes, but it doesn't create the `test` file in the current directory.

```
# ls
Makefile
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong here? Or any tips to debug further? TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default `make` variables are not exported. You probably want to add 'export ARCH' after the assignment.

```
ARCH := $(if $(GOARCH),$(GOARCH),$(shell go env GOARCH))
export ARCH

# OR
export ARCH := $(if $(GOARCH),$(GOARCH),$(shell go env GOARCH))
```

For the `build` action to work you need ARCH to be export for two reason

- The `'[ "$ARCH" = "amd64" ];` refer to environment variable ARCH
- The actual build will probably need ARCH set correctly to work.